# Herokuへデプロイしたアプリのブラウザ表示で「Application error」となる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, デプロイ

プログラミング初心者です。
ruby 2.5.7
Rails 5.2.0

railsチュートリアルの１章、{1.5.3}を行っています。
vagrant環境内でただ文字が表示されるだけの「hello_app」というアプリを作り、デプロイをしようとしており、

```
$ git push heroku master
```

まではうまくいったのですが、ブラウザ表示ができません。

`heroku open` コマンドでは以下の様になり、

```
 $ heroku open
     ▸    Error opening web browser.
     ▸    Error: Exited with code 3
     ▸    
     ▸    Manually visit https://boiling-inlet-44956.herokuapp.com/ in your browser.
```

ブラウザでURLを直接指定するとブラウザに以下の様に表示されます。

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

`heroku logs --tail`コマンドを行うと長いですが以下の様になります。

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant/hello_app$ heroku logs --tail
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328479+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': libruby.so.2.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so (LoadError)
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328499+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328502+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328505+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328525+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328527+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328529+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328533+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328534+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328536+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328539+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328541+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328544+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328547+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328550+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328569+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328571+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:05:17.328576+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `set -e
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: mkdir -p tmp/repo_tmp/unpack
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: cd tmp/repo_tmp
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: curl -fo repo-cache.tgz 'https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku_repos/heroku.com/cache/155667281.tgz?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIO4SD3DCRO7W6IJQ&Signature=YhboIS1zj4Exk91eTmeQSUJe8OM%3D&Expires=1576238773'
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: cd unpack
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: tar -zxf ../repo-cache.tgz
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: METADATA="vendor/heroku"
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: if [ -d "$METADATA" ]; then
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: TMPDIR=`mktemp -d`
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: cp -rf $METADATA $TMPDIR
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: fi
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: cd ..
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: rm -rf unpack
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: mkdir unpack
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: cd unpack
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: TMPDATA="$TMPDIR/heroku"
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: VENDOR="vendor"
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: if [ -d "$TMPDATA" ]; then
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: mkdir $VENDOR
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: cp -rf $TMPDATA $VENDOR
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: rm -rf $TMPDIR
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: fi
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: tar -zcf ../cache-repack.tgz .
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: curl -fo /dev/null --upload-file ../cache-repack.tgz 'https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku_repos/heroku.com/cache/155667281.tgz?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIO4SD3DCRO7W6IJQ&Signature=9PqFzVwldNhNR65GctzeV5GKi9E%3D&Expires=1576238774'
2019-12-13T11:06:15.941821+00:00 app[api]: exit` by user ******@gmail.com
2019-12-13T11:06:19.498994+00:00 heroku[run.4115]: State changed from starting to up
2019-12-13T11:06:19.674136+00:00 heroku[run.4115]: Awaiting client
2019-12-13T11:06:19.715556+00:00 heroku[run.4115]: Starting process with command `set -e mkdir -p tmp/repo_tmp/unpack cd tmp/repo_tmp curl -fo repo-cache.tgz 'https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku_repos/heroku.com/cache/155667281.tgz?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIO4SD3DCRO7W6IJQ&Signature=YhboIS1zj4Exk91eTmeQSUJe8OM%3D&Expires=1576238773' cd unpack tar -zxf ../repo-cache.tgz METADATA="vendor/heroku" if [ -d "$METADATA" ]; then   TMPDIR=`mktemp -d`   cp -rf $METADATA $TMPDIR fi cd .. rm -rf unpack mkdir unpack cd unpack TMPDATA="$TMPDIR/heroku" VENDOR="vendor" if [ -d "$TMPDATA" ]; then   mkdir $VENDOR   cp -rf $TMPDATA $VENDOR   rm -rf $TMPDIR fi tar -zcf ../cache-repack.tgz . curl -fo /dev/null --upload-file ../cache-repack.tgz 'https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku_repos/heroku.com/cache/155667281.tgz?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIO4SD3DCRO7W6IJQ&Signature=9PqFzVwldNhNR65GctzeV5GKi9E%3D&Expires=1576238774' exit`
2019-12-13T11:06:25.988415+00:00 heroku[run.4115]: State changed from up to complete
2019-12-13T11:06:25.967422+00:00 heroku[run.4115]: Process exited with status 0
2019-12-13T11:07:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ******@gmail.com
2019-12-13T11:08:57.714711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-12-13T11:08:57.380987+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user ******@gmail.com
2019-12-13T11:08:57.380987+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f4b55637 by user ******@gmail.com
2019-12-13T11:09:00.107816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8443 -e production`
2019-12-13T11:09:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-12-13T11:09:02.462006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-13T11:09:02.378932+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': libruby.so.2.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so (LoadError)
2019-12-13T11:09:02.378982+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.378988+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.378990+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.378992+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.378994+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.378998+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379000+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379002+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379003+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379051+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379053+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379056+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379058+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379061+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379063+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379065+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.379069+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2019-12-13T11:09:02.439865+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-12-13T11:09:43.027954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-inlet-44956.herokuapp.com request_id=77687982-8e4d-4278-b965-65e7109264d3 fwd="220.144.186.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-13T11:09:43.797322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-inlet-44956.herokuapp.com request_id=c50b5f88-c956-4d3e-9ad9-a42147866545 fwd="220.144.186.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-13T11:17:11.655899+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-inlet-44956.herokuapp.com request_id=15164495-1883-4c61-bea2-90d60b510b20 fwd="220.144.186.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-13T11:17:12.484512+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-inlet-44956.herokuapp.com request_id=035231b6-2db3-4322-b793-fa46f6eba0a2 fwd="220.144.186.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-13T11:26:38.605356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-12-13T11:26:42.068480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 27644 -e production`
2019-12-13T11:26:44.219808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160600+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': libruby.so.2.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so (LoadError)
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160650+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160686+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160730+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160737+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160742+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160744+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160746+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160747+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160749+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160750+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160754+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160755+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160757+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160765+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160770+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160772+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.160774+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2019-12-13T11:26:44.200208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

`$ heroku run rails console` すると以下の様になります。

```
$ heroku run rails console
Running rails console on ⬢ boiling-inlet-44956... up, run.9914 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    17: from /app/bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
    16: from /app/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    15: from /app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /app/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    13: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    11: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     9: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     7: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
     5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
     4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': libruby.so.2.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so (LoadError)
```

解決方法を色々探していて、下記のサイトを参考に、heroku側のキャッシュの削除を行いました。
https://teratail.com/questions/96685

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
$ heroku repo:purge_cache
```

その後再びherokuへコミットを行いましたが、解決しませんでした。

理解が足りていない為的外れかもしれませんが、下記の様なことも関係しているのか？と考えています。

- railsチュートリアル上ではクラウドIDEを使うのを推奨しているが、自分の場合はvagrantを使って別のrailsアプリを作っていたりするので、vagrantで rails new　するところから始めている
- チュートリアルではgemのバージョンを指定しているが、rails serverが起動しないerrorを回避する為にチュートリアル通りのバージョンにしていない

似た様な質問をされている方々も貼っていることが多い様でしたので、
GemfileとGemfile.lockもコピペします。

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.2'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.6.4'
gem 'bootsnap', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',      '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug', '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
    activerecord (5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (9.0.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (9.0.6)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.5)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.11.3)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.6.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.4.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.13.0)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    multi_json (1.14.1)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (0.20.0)
    puma (3.9.1)
    rack (2.0.7)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.0)
      actioncable (= 5.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      activestorage (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.5.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap
  byebug (= 9.0.6)
  coffee-rails (= 4.2.2)
  jbuilder (= 2.6.4)
  jquery-rails (= 4.3.1)
  listen (= 3.1.5)
  pg (= 0.20.0)
  puma (= 3.9.1)
  rails (= 5.2)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.6)
  spring (= 2.0.2)
  spring-watcher-listen (= 2.0.1)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.13)
  turbolinks (= 5.0.1)
  uglifier (= 3.2.0)
  web-console (= 3.5.1)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

どなたか分かる方、教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

以下のページを参考にしたところ（というか書いてある通りに行ったところ）、解決しました！

[【初心者向け】railsアプリをherokuを使って確実にデプロイする方法【決定版】](https://qiita.com/kazukimatsumoto/items/a0daa7281a3948701c39)

結局何が原因だったのかはわかりませんが、Gemfileの設定、config/datebase.ymlの設定、config/environments/production.rbの設定、bin以下のフォルダの設定をした後に、
Railsアプリとherokuの紐づけをしてデプロイしたところうまくいきました。